# Inclusion proof (set theory)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U$ be a set. Let the sets $A,B\in {\cal P} (U)$. And let their symmetrical
 difference be given by: $A\Delta B = (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) $

I'm to prove that $\forall A,B \in {\cal P}(U) : A\Delta B =
(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$.

Now we have 4 possibilities: 1) $x\in A, x\notin B$ 2) $x\notin A, x\in B$
3) $x\in A,x\in B$ 4) $x\notin A, x\notin B$

If 1) $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$

then $x\in A \setminus B$, $x \notin B \setminus A$ and $x \in A\cup B$, $x\notin 
A\cap B$

so $x \in (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$
and $x\in (A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$

If 2) $x\notin A, x\in B$

then $x\notin A \setminus B$, $x \in B \setminus A$ and $x \in A\cup B$, $x\notin 
A\cap B$

so $x \in (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$
and $x\in (A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$

If 3) $x\in A,x\in B$

then $x \notin A \setminus B$, $x \notin B \setminus A$ and $x \in A\cup B$, 
$x \in A\cap B$

so $x \notin (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$
and $x \notin(A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$

If 4) $x\notin A, x\notin B$

then $x \notin A \setminus B$, $x \notin B \setminus A$ and 
$x \notin A\cup B$, $x \notin A\cap B$

so $x \notin (A\setminus B) \cup (B\setminus A)$
and $x \notin (A\cup B) \setminus (A\cap B)$

So if $x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) $, then
$x\in (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) \to
(A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) \subseteq
(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$

And if $x\in (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$, then
$x\in (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) $
$\to (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B) \subseteq
(A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A)$

$\to (A\setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) =
(A\cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$

Is this proof ok/sufficient?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Oh, I think I edited it away. It originally read "Is this proof ok/sufficient?" Re-edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks OK, but a much simpler version is possible:

$$A\Delta B = (A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A) = (A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap A^c)\\
=(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup A^c) \cap(B^c\cup B)\cap(B^c\cup A^c) \\
=(A\cup B)\cap(B^c\cup A^c)\cap U\cap U\\
=(A\cup B)\cap(B^c\cup A^c) = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c = (A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)$$

All I used here were:

- The definition $X\setminus Y = X\cap Y^c$
- Distributivity of $\cap,\cup$, i.e. $(X\cap Y)\cup Z = (X\cup Z)\cap (Y\cup Z)$
- The fact that $X\cap U=X$ and $X\cup X^c=U$